# Refactoring a mongoid call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Right now, i am using 2 different but very similar queries (difference is just an additional criteria

```
pop_answers = Answer.any_of(
  {:num_likes.gte=>3, :image_filename.exists=>true},
).desc(:created_at).skip(to_skip).limit(per_page).map{|a|a}

pop_answers_in_topic = Answer.any_of(
  {:num_likes.gte=>3, :image_filename.exists=>true, :topic_id=>some_id},
).desc(:created_at).skip(to_skip).limit(per_page).map{|a|a}
```

How can i refactor this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class method to `Answer`:

```
def self.popular(offset, limit, for_topic_id = nil)
  conditions = { :num_likes.gte => 3, :image_filename.exists => true }
  conditions[:topic_id] = for_topic_id if(for_topic_id)
  any_of(conditions).desc(:created_at).skip(offset).limit(limit).map{|a|a}
end
```

Or if you're expecting more than just a topic ID:

```
def self.popular(offset, limit, options = { })
  conditions = { :num_likes.gte => 3, :image_filename.exists => true }.merge(options)
  any_of(conditions).desc(:created_at).skip(offset).limit(limit).map{|a|a}
end
```

I don't use Mongoid but you might be able to drop the funny `.map{|a|a}` or use `.to_a` instead.

Or perhaps something scope-ish:

```
# In answer.rb
def self.popular(for_topic_id = nil)
  conditions = { :num_likes.gte => 3, :image_filename.exists => true }
  conditions[:topic_id] = for_topic_id if(for_topic_id)
  any_of(conditions)
end

# And then where you're using it...
pop_answers  = Answer.popular.desc(:created_at).skip(to_skip).limit(per_page).map{|a|a}
pop_in_topic = Answer.popular(some_id).desc(:created).skip(to_skip).limit(per_page).map{|a|a}
```

And I have to wonder if `any_of` is really what you're looking for here, perhaps [`all_of`](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#all_of) would make more sense.